# Visual Studio Designer Cannot open a file Despite it being the first and only Class in the file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, entity-framework, debugging

Whereas [MSDN suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CodeDomDesignerLoaderNoRootSerializer);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2)&rd=true) that some incompatible behavior might also cause this issue

In my case, The incompatible behavior is caused by some possibly weird(messed up mappings) on Entity Framework.

I have done due diligence to ensure one-to-one correspondence between the data model and the EF model(even recreated it twice, ground up)

The project builds and runs when I comment out a certain section of code.

```
public partial class TestForm : SecureForm
{
    private myEntities _db = new myEntities();

    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PopulateTestsList();
    }

    private void PopulateTestsList()
    {
        listViewTypes.Items.Clear();

        var query = from q in _db.Types orderby q.TypeName select q;

        foreach (Type dt in query)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[]
            {
            dt.TypeName
            });
            lvi.Tag = dt;
            listViewTypes.Items.Add(lvi);
        }

    }

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestEditForm myEditForm = new TestEditForm(_db);
        if (myEditForm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            PopulateTestsList();
    }

    private void buttonEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listViewTypes.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Test tsdt = listViewTypes.SelectedItems[0].Tag as Test;
            if (myEditForm != null)
            {
                TestEditForm myEditForm = new TestEditForm(_db, mysForm);
                if (myEditForm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    PopulateTestsList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It still does not show up the designer.

[image]

Here's the designer.cs for reference

```
partial class TestForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.buttonDelete = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.buttonEdit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.buttonAdd = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.listViewTypes = new System.Windows.Forms.ListView();
        this.columnName = ((System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader)(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader()));
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // buttonDelete
        // 
        this.buttonDelete.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(304, 86);
        this.buttonDelete.Name = "buttonDelete";
        this.buttonDelete.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.buttonDelete.TabIndex = 9;
        this.buttonDelete.Text = "Delete";
        this.buttonDelete.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonDelete.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonDelete_Click);
        // 
        // buttonEdit
        // 
        this.buttonEdit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(304, 56);
        this.buttonEdit.Name = "buttonEdit";
        this.buttonEdit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.buttonEdit.TabIndex = 8;
        this.buttonEdit.Text = "Edit";
        this.buttonEdit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonEdit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonEdit_Click);
        // 
        // buttonAdd
        // 
        this.buttonAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(304, 26);
        this.buttonAdd.Name = "buttonAdd";
        this.buttonAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.buttonAdd.TabIndex = 7;
        this.buttonAdd.Text = "Add";
        this.buttonAdd.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonAdd.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonAdd_Click);
        // 
        // listViewTypes
        // 
        this.listViewTypes.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.columnName});
        this.listViewTypes.FullRowSelect = true;
        this.listViewTypes.HideSelection = false;
        this.listViewTypes.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 26);
        this.listViewTypes.Name = "listViewTypes";
        this.listViewTypes.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(274, 205);
        this.listViewTypes.TabIndex = 6;
        this.listViewTypes.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.listViewTypes.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        // 
        // columnName
        // 
        this.columnName.Text = "Document Type";
        this.columnName.Width = 270;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 10);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(79, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 5;
        this.label1.Text = "Test Standards";
        // 
        // TestsForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(395, 242);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonDelete);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonEdit);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonAdd);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listViewTypes);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "TestsForm";
        this.Opacity = 1D;
        this.Text = "Test Standards";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonDelete;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonEdit;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonAdd;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListView listViewTypes;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader columnName;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
}
```

Code analysis shows that the form is missing,(MSBuild does not). MSBUILD compiles the form into an exe thats kinda defunct(on the broken entity)

The entity in question has Name & ID properties. Both Name and ID are mapped properly, The collection is pluralized and loaded into a list.

How to identify the broken entity and/or

How to Identify the non-compatible behavior in the code

Comment: Can you post the entire class file?

Comment: Hey Ron, Just Did.

Comment: There is no problem in the code that you shared. The problem probably resides in `SecureForm` ...

Comment: SecureForm is a tested Interface implemented across all forms. I have not done anything different here(as opposed to the other forms) good viewpoint though

Comment: Strange, but Recreating the entire form ground up once again. worked.

Comment: the number of differences between the old copy and the working copy on winmerge : 0

Comment: Perhaps its got something to do with the call stack

Comment: @DL Narasimhan, So it works well now, am I right? I met the designer issue before, sometimes it was related to the project file loaded or others. For example, we often re-open the form file in solution explorer window, or delete the .suo file, and then re-open the .xxproj file.